# How to seed initial data after adding new entity?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I've noticed a **Seed** folder in **MyProject.EntityFrameworkCore** project with the code to seed initial data to the database.

If I add code to populate the database with my new entity, where and how will the code be called?

Do the .NET Core and the full .NET Framework versions work the same way?

Comment: [Seeding is now supported as a context method.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is run:

1. On application startup, called in the `PostInitialize` method of [`YourEntityFrameworkModule`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/63f6e3b6147b6df7a08b09a53dad562c57dac17c/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/AbpProjectNameEntityFrameworkModule.cs#L46):

   ```cs
   public override void PostInitialize()
   {
       if (!SkipDbSeed)
       {
           SeedHelper.SeedHostDb(IocManager);
       }
   }
   ```
2. If you build **Migrator** project and run the **.exe**, called in `Run` method of [`MultiTenantExecuter`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/63f6e3b6147b6df7a08b09a53dad562c57dac17c/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Migrator/MultiTenantMigrateExecuter.cs#L62):

   ```cs
   public void Run(bool skipConnVerification)
   {
       // ...

       Log.Write("HOST database migration started...");

       try
       {
           _migrator.CreateOrMigrateForHost(SeedHelper.SeedHostDb);
       }
       // ...
   }
   ```

If you add new code to populate your custom entity, remember to check before adding, like [this](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/b5c18c989fa236d768d3ec6662edb5d66b4612c3/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/Seed/Host/DefaultEditionCreator.cs#L25-L30):

```cs
var defaultEdition = _context.Editions.IgnoreQueryFilters().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == EditionManager.DefaultEditionName);
if (defaultEdition == null)
{
    // ...

    /* Add desired features to the standard edition, if wanted... */
}
```

Yes, the .NET Core and full .NET Framework versions work the same way.

Comment: is the method 2 alternative to the 1? used for production db, for example?

Comment: Yes to both questions.